# How to save form values to JSON with save dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

This [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt4Rz/) will submit the form values, but I would like the submit button to serialize to JSON instead and open a save dialog box. It must work offline, so only HTML and JS.

**Question**

Does there exist a JQuery plugin there can do this? If not, which JS function should I look into?

**JS**

```
$("#myform").dform({
    "action" : "index.html",
    "method" : "get",
    "html" :
    [
        {
            "type" : "p",
            "html" : "You must login"
        },
        {
            "name" : "username",
            "id" : "txt-username",
            "caption" : "Username",
            "type" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "E.g. user@example.com"
        },
        {
            "name" : "password",
            "caption" : "Password",
            "type" : "password"
        },
        {
            "type" : "submit",
            "value" : "Login"
        }
    ]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform"></form>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
}

label, input {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you should check the dform documentation or just use .serialize() on a standard

Comment: Not exactly related, but where are you submitting a form to when offline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `serializeArray()` in jQuery that helps you easily build the json:

```
$("#myform").on('submit', function(e){

    // prevent default submit action
    e.preventDefault();

    var serialized = $(this).serializeArray(),
        obj = {};

    // build key-values
    $.each(serialized, function(){
       obj [this.name] = this.value;
    });

    // and the json string
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);

    console.log(json);
    // send your data here...

});
```

The dialog box is a broader topic ;)

Comment: By save dialog box I mean the standard that the OS provides. E.g. when you click on a download link.

Comment: Without a server that generates the file to save, it gets a little more complicated. You would have to build a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob), append the data to it, the get the URL to it. Are you sure this is what you want? Because saving a user name and password to a json file seems a little weird to me

Comment: Ok, I see the problem... The username/password is just an example. I want to make a kiosk where people are shown some pictures on paper, and they should write in the browser what they see, and then save the result to a file. The computer only has Firefox/Chrome and no Internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the blob keyword. FileSaver.js can do exactly this. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js